# A question regarding an algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I'm a software developer, and I wrote an [algorithm](https://avi12.com/nine-calculator) for converting any positive integer with at least 2 digits into 9, based on what [Scott Flansburg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zokbvriYovw&t=10m44s) discovered.

For example: $N = 22$
Sum up the digits: $2 + 2 = 4$
Then, subtract the result from the original number: $22 - 4 = 18$
The sum of the digits: $1 + 8 = 9$
It is valid for any positive integer with at least 2 digits.

Why does the algorithm work?
Is there a name for this algorithm?

EDIT:
I'm not a mathematician, only a math enthusiast, so I'd appreciate it if the answers wouldn't be complex

Comment: The difference (third step) is a multiple of $9$ and this is preserved by taking the digit sum

Comment: It can take some more steps until $9$ is reached , but eventually we will arrive there since the digit sum is smaller than the number as long as we have at least two digits and because of Henry's comment.

Comment: This trick with the "$9$" is however a quite "old hat".

Answer (score 4):

If the number is $xy$, it can be written as $10x+y$. So the second step results in $10x+y-(x+y)=9x$, and we know that the sum of digits of a number that is divisible by $9$ is (eventually) $9$.

Comment: How does this apply to numbers with more than 2 digits? E.g., 123

Comment: Add terms with higher powers of $10$ to get instead of $9$ arguments of the form $10^n-1=9...9$: $10^2x+10y+z-(x+y+z)=99x+9y=9(...)$.

Comment: Ok, and where does the $9x$ come from? Sorry for asking silly questions. I'm just trying to get to the bottom of this

Comment: Which $9x$? Did you mean the $99x=10^2x-x$?

Comment: Yes, and the $9x$ in your main reply

Comment: Open the brackets: $10x-x=9x$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the digits of a number is congruent with itself modulo 9 (this comes from the fact that $10\equiv 1 \mod(9)$, therefore $10^k \equiv 1 \mod(9)$, so, for example, $123=1\times 10^2+2\times 10+3\times 1\equiv 1+2+3=6$). This is commonly used to test divisibility by 9, but in your case, what you are doing is basically subtracting the number's remainder when dividing by 9, getting to a multiple of 9, so when you sum the digits again you get 9 or a multiple of 9.